# Did Solomon make up his mind to cut the baby?

Tags: solomon, wisdom

What is Solomon mind when he prayed the Lord to give his wisdom to judge ?  Did he think the kingdom is His own ?

Comment: There is no textual answer, because the text does not describe his thoughts. But for the scene, it was necessary only that his act be convincing.

Comment: @Paul Welcome to BH and thanks for your question. Do read the tour to see guidelines on how this site works, then you may like to edit into your question the Scriptures that suggest to you uncertainty of meaning.  Without clearer definition your question is likely to be Closed.

Comment: We're glad to have you here. Make sure you take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour). We need a specific Bible verse or Bible study method in our questions. If you can add that, click Flag and ask for a moderator to review the post.

Answer (score 1):

The account in the Bible you seem to refer to is 1 Kings chapter 3. The answer, as to whether king Solomon intended to have the baby cut in half, can be surmised from starting at verse 1, then considering the last verse in the same chapter.

The idea that he ***"pretended to cut the baby",*** has no basis, for there is no hint of any dramatic action when the sword Solomon requested was brought into the banquet hall. It was merely what he said to the sword-bearer that caused the genuine mother of the living baby to instantly speak up before any harm could come to her baby, proving the other woman's baby had died in the night, and she had been lying. Solomon merely had to speak, and the case was settled. That is what the account clearly shows.

As for the idea that he ***"had made up his mind to cut the baby"***, that is dispelled by the context of the chapter. Consider what God had granted to Solomon starting at verse 5. He appeared in a dream to Solomon to invite him to make a request of God. Solomon did not ask for wealth, or for long life, or for the life of his enemies, but for wisdom to judge the people of Israel. God was pleased to grant him that (and wealth with honour, besides). Just before the incident with the two women contesting the one living baby, God told Solomon:

> "Lo, I have given to thee a heart, wise and understanding, that like
> thee there hath not been before thee, and after thee there doth not
> arise like thee" 1 Kings 3:11-12 Y.L.T.

The event of the baby and Solomon's judgment to ascertain the real mother is proof of God having granted that request of exceptional wisdom, in order to judge the people of God correctly. Consider the last verse of that chapter:

> "And all Israel hear of the judgment that the king hath judged, and
> fear because of the king, for they have seen that the wisdom of God
> [is] in his heart, to do judgment." (*Ibid*, vs. 28)

Comment: How much is Solomon judgement reflect the salvation or final judgement ?

Comment: You mean Solomon neither  Made his mind to cut the baby Nor he pretended to cut the baby ? How is that wisdom working ?

Comment: @Paul  The Bible account tells us everything we can know about the event. Anything else is speculation. His wisdom shone through due to the way he quickly prevented the second baby dying or being handed to the wrong mother. The whole nation realised, through the event, that this new king was, indeed, using godly wisdom. Your first comment requires you to post a new question, but I suggest Stack Christianity.